# How to use mktime php

Tags: php

How to get following result

```
2015-08-04T17:14:45.418+01:00
```

I tried Make time method but unable to get same result

```
echo date('c', mktime(17, 14, 45, 8, 4, 2015));
Result
2015-08-04T17:14:45-07:00
```

Comment: Where from is coming -07:00 i do not want minus sign i want .418+01:00 instead of -07:00

Comment: Check your TIMEZONE settings in PHP.INI or set you timezone from code before doing any time related functions [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: You wont get `.418` because it doesn't exist in your `mktime()` params.

Comment: Thankyou for quick response , 
the time which i wanted to get is Spain time .
So it means if i will send this time stamp it wont be problem.
Thankyou again

Answer (score 0):

The minus sign comes from your timezone settings.
Try adjusting it with `date_default_timezone_set` function if you need another timezone. See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: Thankyou for quick response , 
the time which i wanted to get is Spain time .
So it means if i will send this time stamp it wont be problem.
Thankyou again for info